# How to fix code with combined formatted string literals and triple quotes in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a script to automate some meshing and need to output a text file in a certain format. Im using F before my triple quotes but it says there's a syntax error when closing the file.write() at the end of the code. not sure why. Thanks in advance.

```
with open('/Users/aben/blockMeshDict','w') as file:
    file.write(F'''

FoamFile
{{
    version     2.0;
    format      ascii;
    class       dictionary;
    object      blockMeshDict;
}}


convertToMeters 1;

vertices
(
    (0 0 -0.1)
    (0.6 0 -0.1)
    (0 0.2 -0.1)
    (0.6 0.2 -0.1)
    (3 0.2 -0.1)
    (0 1 -0.1) 
    (0.6 1 -0.1) 
    (3 1 -0.1) 
    (0 0 0.1) 
    (0.6 0 0.1) 
    (0 0.2 0.1) 
    (0.6 0.2 0.1) 
    (3 0.2 0.1)
    (0 1 0.1) 
    (0.6 1 0.1)
    (3 1 0.1)
);

blocks
(
    hex (0 1 3 2 8 9 11 10) ({x0} {y0} 1) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (2 3 6 5 10 11 14 13) ({x1} {y1} 1) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
    hex (3 4 7 6 11 12 15 14) ({x2} {y2} 1) simpleGrading (1 1 1)
);''')
```

Comment: Are you actually using a Python version that supports f-strings? What version are you on?

Comment: The code you posted has no syntax errors, assuming you are using a new enough version of Python.

Comment: What is your python version? is should be at least Python 3.6